# Python ThreadPoolExecutor wait for all futures to complete

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am trying to write a module which needs to crawl some URLs concurrently/parallelly. since this would be a more expensive Network IO operation instead of CPU heavy. I am using ThreadPoolExecutor.

Now in my code, multiple functions add tasks to the shared thread pool.

> my issue is Main thread gets suspended before all future objects are
>   done processing in the callback functions.

I am a beginner dealing with futures and ThreadPoolExecutor. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import settings
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import concurrent.futures


class Test(Base):

    WORKER_THREADS = settings.WORKER_THREADS

    def __init__(self, urls):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.urls = urls
        self.worker_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=Test.WORKER_THREADS)


    def add_to_worker_queue(self, task, callback, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info("Adding task %s to worker pool.", task.func_name)
        self.worker_pool.submit(task, **kwargs).add_done_callback(callback)
        return

    def load_url(self, url):
        response = self.make_requests(urls=url) # make_requests is in Base class (it just makes a HTTP req)
        # response is a generator, so to get the data out of it need to iterate through it.
        for res in response:
            return res

    def handle_response(self, response):
        # do some stuff with response and add it again to the worker queue for further parallel processing
        self.add_to_worker_queue(some_task, callback_func, data=response)
        return

    def start(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            self.add_to_worker_queue(self.load_url, self.handle_response, url=[url])
        return

    def stop(self):
        self.worker_pool.shutdown(wait=True)
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_urls = [ 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
                , 'https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html'
                  ]
    test = Test(urls=start_urls)
    test.start()
    test.stop()
```

PS I tried using executer with "with" statement, according to this example. https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example
but as I submit tasks to the pool one by one and above example wait for future objects to be completed which defeats my purpose.

Comment: You say the main thread gets suspended. Where does it get suspended? When it gets to `test.stop()`, since you have `wait=True`, it will naturally suspend there. If you want to do other things before that point, simply do other things before that point :)

Comment: @Julien according to the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown) shouldn't it wait at `test.stop()` before exiting out?